# Limit notions in probability (distribution function)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus

In the literature of Shiryaev on probability, $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is an n-variate distribution function if the following holds  (leaving aside a notion concerning its sign):

(1) $x^{(k)} \downarrow x \implies F(x^{(k)}) \to F(x)$ where $x^{(k)}=(x_1^{k},..,x_n^{k})$,
(2) $F(+\infty,...,+ \infty)=1$, and (3) $\lim_{x \downarrow y} F(x_1,...,x_n)=0$, if at least one of the coordinates of y is $- \infty$.

In a problem at the end of the chapter, he defines a function:

$G(x,y)=1, x+y \geq 0$ and $G(x,y)=0, x+y < 0$.

He claims that this function is right continuous, continuous in each variable, but not a distribution function in the above sense.

As for right continuous, I suppose that he is considering sequences $x^{(k)}$, $x_{i}^{k} \geq x_{i}$ each $i$, and that he by $F(+\infty,...,+\infty)$ considers $\lim_{k \to \infty}F(x^{(k)})$ for some sequence $x^{(k)}=(x_1^{k},..,x_n^{k})$ with $x_i^{(k)} \to +\infty$ as $k \to \infty$, each $i$ .

But it seems that the function is not continuous in each variable separately. As for showing that they are not "distribution functions", one notes that

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} G(n,-m)=0\neq1=\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} G(n,-m)$,

but these limits are treated separately and jointly it seems to me another matter, given the notation used above. If I somehow fix $x=+\infty$ it seems to be in accord with his definition, while for example $\lim_{n \to \infty} G(n+1/2,-n)$ seem not. I'd need some clarification on these asymptotic notions of his.

Comment: In addition to the above function $G$ he defines the function $F(x,y)=[x,y]$, that he refers to as "the nearest integer function".

Comment: I did not want to pass to any measure kind of argument but noticing that $G(n,-n)=1$ for all $n$ and that, under the assumption $G$ can be associated with a measure $P$, $G(n,-n)=P((-\infty,n] \times (-\infty,-n] )\leq P(\mathbb{R} \times (-\infty, -n]) \to 0, n \to \infty$ would be my suggestion, but then again I'm here with all these limits.

Comment: So long this argument goes it seems I should be able to exchange limits in accordance with above, but should I not then find some conditions without involving the associated measure?